# Weird screen settings on docking station

Tags: resolution

When I set my Lenovo X220 Tablet onto the docking station where a 1920x1200 screen is attached via Display Port -> DVI, both the internal and the external screen show the greatest common resolution which is 1024x768.

I can then set the display settings within KDE, but that is rather time consuming. Is there a way to set up the displays correctly when the notebook is in the docking station? Os can I write a shell script that sets the displays correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `xrandr`, I managed to write [a script](https://github.com/martin-ueding/think-rotate) for it.

The main part is this:

```
case "$1" in
    on)
        xrandr --output "$internal" --auto
        xrandr --output "$external" --auto --right-of "$internal" --primary
        ;;
    off)
        xrandr --output "$internal" --auto --primary
        xrandr --output "$external" --off
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

In my "Displays" menu (12.04) there is a checkbox "Mirror displays". If you uncheck it you can choose individual resolutions for each display. If you want to mirror the display both have to have the same resolution. Don't know how to get it higher. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do know how to set the displays to the correct resolution. My problem is that it does not stay that way after rebooting.

Comment: Ah, OK. Had some problems with that too but not since 11.10. Maybe you should edit your question. It sounds a little like it is impossible to set another resolution ;-)